# Logback add Error appender made the others appenders not work

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback, spring-logback

Here is my logback.xml;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <property name="LOGS" value="./logs"/>

    <appender name="Console"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %d{ISO8601} %highlight(%-5level) [%blue(%t)] %yellow(%C{1.} [%M#%L]) %X{serialID}: %msg%n%throwable
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="RollingFile"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOGS}/info-file.log</file>
        <encoder
                class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d %highlight(%-5level) [%blue(%t)] %yellow(%C{1.} [%M#%L]) : %msg%n%throwable</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="DexLogFile"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOGS}/dex.log</file>
        <encoder
                class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d %highlight(%-5level) [%blue(%t)] %yellow(%C{1.} [%M#%L]) : %msg%n%throwable</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ErrorLogFile"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOGS}/error.log</file>
        <encoder
                class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d %highlight(%-5level) [%blue(%t)] %yellow(%C{1.} [%M#%L]) : %msg%n%throwable</Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <!-- LOG everything at INFO level -->
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile"/>
    </root>


    <logger name="com.ssca" level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="DexLogFile"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="ur.company" level="trace" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="ur.company" level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="ur.company" level="error" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="ErrorLogFile"/>
    </logger>

</configuration>
```

I just wanna a **clearly error log file**, so I tried to redirect error to the error.log, so I added those lines:

```
 <logger name="ur.company" level="error" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="ErrorLogFile"/>
 </logger>
```

Without this code, everything was fine. However once I added those lines, the RollingFile appender and Console appender did not work any more...

It's like log level problem, but I tried to remove additivity, not work either.

I've read the logback website, but didn't find any helpfuls.

---

I used lombok @slf4j annotation, Does that cause this conflicts?

Comment: Add Appender Ref inside <root level='info'>  tag . this will work

Comment: @NilayTiwari I did add them

Comment: will that work .

Comment: no, not work, I add `Console` & `RollingFile` Appenders at the begining.

Answer (score 1):

well, I just add filter into the error appender, and put the appender-ref from error level logger to info level logger. Code is like below:

```
 <appender name="ErrorLogFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>ERROR</level>
        </filter>
        <file>${LOGS}/error.log</file>
       ........
 </appender>
```

AND

```
<logger name="ur.company" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile"/>
        <appender-ref ref="ErrorLogFile"/>
</logger>
```